# tkinter GUI design: managing variables from multiple widgets/toolbars

Tags: python-3.x, model-view-controller, tkinter

*{Edit: the answer by Bryan Oakley in the suggested duplicate question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876229/how-to-run-a-code-whenever-a-tkinter-widget-value-changes)  a) fires a response on change to the array variable (arrayvar.trace mode="w"), and I need it triggered on FocusOut, as described in my original question; b) works for Python 2, but I'm having trouble converting it to work in Python 3.5. I'm currently using his and pyfunc's answers as leads and trying to figure out a similar solution using a FocusOut event.}*

I am working on a tkinter GUI that lets a user select a particular type of calculation, using a pair of radio button lists. Based on the selections, a tool bar is populated with multiple modular entry widgets, one for each variable the calculation requires. The goal is to have the numerical entry values passed to the model, which will return data to be graphed on a canvas or matplotlib widget.

My question is: what typical strategy is used for gathering and continually refreshing values from multiple widgets, in order to update displays and to pass them on to the model? The trick here is that there will be a large number of possible calculation types, each with their own toolbar. I'd like the active toolbar to be "aware" of its contents, and ping the model on every change to a widget entry.

I think the widgets and the toolbar would have to be classes, where the toolbar can query each widget for a fresh copy of its entry values when a change is detected, and store them as some collection that is passed to the model. I'm not entirely sure how it can track changes to the widgets. Using a "validate='focusout' " validation on the entry widget (e.g. as in 
[this validation reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry-validation.html) )
suggests itself, but I already use "validate='key' " to limit all entries to numbers. I don't want to use "validate=all" and piggyback onto it because I don't want to continually ask the model to do a lengthy calculation on every keypress.

I'm new to GUI programming, however, so I may be barking up the wrong tree. I'm sure there must be a standard design pattern to address this, but I haven't found it.

Below is a screenshot of a mockup to illustrate what I want the GUI to do. The Task radiobutton controls which secondary button menu appears below. The selection in the second menu populates the top toolbar with the necessary entry widgets.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a code whenever a Tkinter widget value changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876229/how-to-run-a-code-whenever-a-tkinter-widget-value-changes)

Comment: Have you tried creating a binding to `<FocusOut>`? It sounds like that's all you need.

Comment: @BryanOakley That's what I'm going to try tonight. I think then I don't need ArrayVar, but can make a plain dictionary in the parent toolbar frame. Then, have widgets "on FocusOut, store the contents in the dictionary and call the 'ping model' routine".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does (mostly) what I want. The ToolBar frame objects will store the values from its contained widgets, and call the appropriate model as needed. The VarBox objects are Entry widgets with extra functionality. Hitting Tab or Return refreshes the data stored in the ToolBar dictionary, tells the ToolBar to send data to the model, and shifts focus to the next VarBox widget.

```
from tkinter import *


# Actual model would be imported. "Dummy" model for testing below.
def dummy_model(dic):
    """
    A "dummy" model for testing the ability for a toolbar to ping the model.
    Argument:
    -dic: a dictionary whose values are numbers.
    Result:
    -prints the sum of dic's values.
    """
    total = 0
    for value in dic.values():
        total += value
    print('The total of the entries is: ', total)


class ToolBar(Frame):
    """
    A frame object that contains entry widgets, a dictionary of
    their current contents, and a function to call the appropriate model.
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **options):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, **options)
        self.vars = {}

    def call_model(self):
        print('Sending to dummy_model: ', self.vars)
        dummy_model(self.vars)


class VarBox(Frame):
    """
    A customized Frame containing a numerical entry box
    Arguments:
    -name: Name of the variable; appears above the entry box
    -default: default value in entry
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None, name='', default=0.00, **options):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, relief=RIDGE, borderwidth=1, **options)
        Label(self, text=name).pack(side=TOP)
        self.widgetName = name  # will be key in dictionary

        # Entries will be limited to numerical
        ent = Entry(self, validate='key')  # check for number on keypress
        ent.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
        self.value = StringVar()
        ent.config(textvariable=self.value)
        self.value.set(str(default))
        ent.bind('<Return>',   lambda event: self.to_dict(event))
        ent.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda event: self.to_dict(event))

        # check on each keypress if new result will be a number
        ent['validatecommand'] = (self.register(self.is_number), '%P')
        # sound 'bell' if bad keypress
        ent['invalidcommand'] = 'bell'

    @staticmethod
    def is_number(entry):
        """
        tests to see if entry is acceptable (either empty, or able to be
        converted to a float.)
        """
        if not entry:
            return True  # Empty string: OK if entire entry deleted
        try:
            float(entry)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    def to_dict(self, event):
        """
        On event: Records widget's status to the container's dictionary of
        values, fills the entry with 0.00 if it was empty, tells the container
        to send data to the model, and shifts focus to the next entry box (after
        Return or Tab).
        """
        if not self.value.get():    # if entry left blank,
            self.value.set(0.00)    # fill it with zero
        # Add the widget's status to the container's dictionary
        self.master.vars[self.widgetName] = float(self.value.get())
        self.master.call_model()
        event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()


root = Tk()  # create app window
BarParentFrame = ToolBar(root)  # holds individual toolbar frames
BarParentFrame.pack(side=TOP)
BarParentFrame.widgetName = 'BarParentFrame'

# Pad out rest of window for visual effect
SpaceFiller = Canvas(root, width=800, height=600, bg='beige')
SpaceFiller.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

Label(BarParentFrame, text='placeholder').pack(expand=NO, fill=X)
A = VarBox(BarParentFrame, name='A', default=5.00)
A.pack(side=LEFT)
B = VarBox(BarParentFrame, name='B', default=3.00)
B.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```